# Find a generic Name

Tags: excel, vba, database-design

I have a bit of a problem regarding a large database with many different names for the same company. Basically, what I have to do is find all the names representing Company X and change them to "X".

This way, if the detailed name is "X SL" or "Shipment Regarder ASL" or "oubiyubib(2)" and we know that all three represent company "X", I'd have to look for them and change them by hand. There's also something called "NISA" that's meant to represent the sector the company is in, since sometimes the one that comes in the files I'm to process are wrong.

To solve this, I created an excel that stores all known names for the various companies and then replaces the names on the list accordingly. The structure of the stored data goes like this:

[image: Captura]
So in the first column there's the "NISA" and the second one has the generic name for the company, while on the columns following that are the known names for the company. The whole name lists are alphabetized by the column with a "1".

Then, there's "INDICE" which details the row where the first instance with the three letter combination appears. This way, the first name starting with "3SU" is in row 28. "INDICIE 2" is to detail the first letter in "INDICE", so an index of an index. Meaning that the first row in "INDICE" starting with an "A" would be in row 39.

The main reason for all this is because the database quickly grew to contain over 25K rows and over a hundred columns in some instances, and because sometimes "3MSA" is an entirely different company than "3MSL", the thing has to go word for word checking over which it'd be its appropriate generic name.

So the bulk of the code goes like this:

```
Dim listRow As Long, searchRow As Long
Dim searchedName As String, genericName As String
Dim problem As Boolean
problem = False
listRow = 2
searchRow = 2
searchedName = ""
genericName = ""

Do While Cells(listRow, colmnNames) <> ""
    searchedName = UCase(Cells(listRow, colmnNames))
    searchRow = 0
    'This part compares if it's looking again for the same name. If it is, it'll just copy the previous results
    If Cells(listRow, colmnNames) = Cells(listRow - 1, colmnNames) Then
        Cells(listRow, colmnResults) = Cells(listRow - 1, colmnResults)
        Cells(listRow, colmnRestNisa) = Cells(listRow - 1, colmnRestNisa)
        Cells(listRow, errorsA) = Cells(listRow - 1, errorsA)
        Cells(listRow, errorsB) = Cells(listRow - 1, errorsB)
    Else
        Cells(listRow, colmnNames).Select
        searchRow = IndexRunner(searchedName) '" IndexRunner " will return the row it will have to start looking, if it's 0 then it means the starting letter combination doesn't exist
        If searchRow > 0 Then
            searchRow = Finder(searchRow, searchedName) '"Finder" will traverse the database row by row, running the columns until it reaches a blank comparing name by name until it finds a match. If it gets outside the starting 3 letter combination, it stops and returns 0, otherwise, it'll return the row where it found the match
            If searchRow > 0 Then
                Cells(listRow, colmnResults) = Cells(searchRow, "B")
                Cells(listRow, colmnRestNisa) = Cells(searchRow, "A")
            Else
                GoTo NotFound
            End If
        Else
NotFound: 

            Cells(listRow, colmnResults) = searchedName
            Cells(listRow, colmnRestNisa) = Cells(listRow, colmnSectores)
            Cells(listRow, errorsA) = searchedName
            Cells(listRow, errorsB) = Cells(listRow, colmnSectores)
            Cells(listRow, erroresC) = "Not Found"
            problem = True 'This is so there'll be a popup at the end of the loop.
        End If
    End If
    listRow = listRow + 1
Loop
```

Because the code centers around the "Only go at it while the first three letters of the name match", I've been able to considerably cut down processing time, but it can still take nearly an hour to go through a 50K long name list, so at this point I'm wondering if there's any way to either make this go at it faster in VBA or just some other way to structure all this out.

NOTE: I don't have access to other software and where I work at they have strict "NOT ALLOWED" rules to add anything to the computers, so I'm stuck with excel VBA until someone up above gets a hint.

Comment: I proposed a possibilty to speed up your code, but is this sufficient enough? Or do you also want to restructure your code anyway?

Answer (score 1):

For the beginning, if you want to speed up your code, you can use this code fragment:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual
```

Put it after your `Dim` section and at the end of the code put in the same fragment and change the values back to `true` respecitively `xlAutomatic`

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
```

In my case it increased the speed of the code. I don't know how the performance changes if you skip the `DisplayAlerts` line in order to show alerts in case there are some.

If you also want to restructure your code it will take a bit more time.

Comment: I already was using the "ScreenUpdating=False" piece of code, and with the other four it seems to go only marginally faster from a test I just finished (saved me 5 minutes). I don't particularly care if it needs a full reformat, I'd just like to know if there's at least some other structure I could follow to make this more efficient/faster.

Comment: Could you also provide the `Indexrunner` and `Finder` code to the question? Currently I can only guess why it takes so long. In addition, a computers takes longer to compare string values than numbers. In this case I would replace `Cells(searchRow, "B")` with `Cells(searchRow, 2)` the same with "A"